# object in php get the array if name contains '.'

Tags: php, drupal

I am trying to get an array from within an object using the following php code.

```
 $abstract = $view->result[0]->nye.abstract;
```

i am getting a syntax error with this because of the '.' in nye.abstract.
Is there anyway around this problem?

FYI the view is a drupal view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$abstract = $view->result[0]->{'nye.abstract'};
```

Answer (score 1):

2 ways to overpass this problem:

**By variable:**

```
$nye="nye.abstract";
$abstract = $view->result[0]->$nye;
```

**With curly brackets:**

```
$abstract = $view->result[0]->{'nye.abstract'};
```